# Override configuration with UseSetting

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, configuration

I am using .NET Core 2.2, default template and trying to override configuration using UseSetting, however I can't make it work. Test value set in config to File, I would like to override it with same value in Code, and then in Startup I want to get overridden value.

(Originally I was trying to add AzureKeyVaultProvider, but it was not working for me and I've ended with this example)

Configuration:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Test": "file" 
}
```

Program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseSetting("Test", "code");
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var value = _configuration.GetValue<string>("Test");
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `UseSetting` applies to the *host* configuration, which is applied *before* the application's configuration. You'll need to hook into [`ConfigureAppConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilder.configureappconfiguration?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: @KirkLarkin Originally I was trying to override configuration with: WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseConfiguration(configuration), which I expect to be the way to override configuration, however when I checked source code `UseConfiguration` just iterates over configuration keys and calls UseSetting for each of them. That's why I expect UseSetting to override configuration, not only host configuration

Comment: And even before that, I was trying to add AzureKeyVault according to this example: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/Services/Ordering/Ordering.API/Program.cs. Values are getting retrieved, but not override config file

Comment: It is not answer to my question, as I wanted to override configuration using `UseConfiguration` extension, like this: `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseConfiguration(configuration)`, but it solves my original problem, so I am accepting it

Comment: The problem would still be the same, because `UseConfiguration` also applies to the *host* As you said, it just wraps up `UseSetting`. Host configuration gets copied into application configuration, so it usually works, the JSON file in your example overrides these values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UseSetting` applies to the *host* configuration, which is applied *before* the application's configuration. In your example, it's the JSON value that overrides the `UseSetting` value. `UseSetting` sets the value in the host configuration, which gets copied into the application configuration and then *overridden* by the JSON value.

Use [`ConfigureAppConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilder.configureappconfiguration?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and [`AddInMemoryCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.memoryconfigurationbuilderextensions.addinmemorycollection?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to achieve the desired result:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, configurationBuilder) =>
    {
        configurationBuilder.AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            ["Test"] = "code"
        });
    });
```

With this setup, values used in the call to `AddInMemoryCollection` override all other values in JSON, env, etc.